# Cases created by high-volume portal users become inaccessible

Tags: customer-portal, servicecloud

[Service Cloud Portal](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_about_HVPUs.htm) users are those users with a High-volume portal license type. There are requirements that typically mean you'll need to use this license type viz.

- You anticipate more than 300k users
- The users won't need access to CRM objects beyond Account, Contact and Case (and some others)
- You need access to custom objects
- The data sharing requirement is simple

This is fine and dandy but I've noticed that there's a large issue that blocks - what I would call - the typical case-resolution process i.e.

> You can’t transfer cases from non-high-volume portal users to high-volume portal users.

So if your case-resolution process includes a step where a case record, created by someone from your HVP, is then assigned to anyone who isn't an HVP user then the record can never be owned by the HVP user ever again! Additionally I've noticed that if the HVP user is associated with a Person Account then Sharing Sets don't work meaning the user can never see their case again.

Am I doing something wrong here, or have I found a limitation of the platform?

*I assume there are work-arounds through code but would prefer to use declarative features* :)

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is a platform limitation. In a project I did with high-volume portal users we ran into several areas where standard features were either unsupported or had major issues. Can't really think of a code workaround for your issue that involves true assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you might have an error in your configuration (Which isn't surprising, there are a few things you have to do to get it working correctly).

If:

1. The HVCP user is the Contact on the Case and
2. you have a sharing set associated with the profile you are using for your HVCP

Then when the case owner changed from the HVCP user to an internal party, they should still retain rights to the Case.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct _except_ if the HVCP user is associated with a Person Account, then the "Access Determined By" feature doesn't seem to recognise the match. I've alluded to this in my question above, but your answer is great otherwise :)

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect, it has nothing to do with Person Accounts and everything to do with my configuring it incorrectly :) Your answer led me to the solution.

Comment: It seems you can only create one sharing set per named profile, with each sharing set providing access to multiple objects at once. Once you've used a profile in a sharing set *it is unavailable to any other sharing set*. I was trying to create a sharing set per object. #fail

Comment: Ah.  There you go.  I thought about the 'Person Account' thing but since we'd just finished a project with Person Accounts and HVCP and encountered no issues I'd assumed it wouldn't be a problem.   I will say one more thing, I cannot get Account's to appear for HVCP users, despite the documentation saying its possible...

Comment: I can read and edit accounts but it has to happen from a VF page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: With a standard controller?  With a custom controller you can do anything...

Comment: Yep, standard controller.